# how to stop a while loop with two consecutive same strings form user input and then prints out the rest of the strings

Tags: python, string, while-loop

I am a complete beginner currently doing a online course of python to challenge myself and i have hit a wall so to speak. I would like to know how to stop a while loop using the word stop or two consecutive same words.
This is the current code that i have:

```
all = "" #store variable
while True:
entry = input("Enter a word: ")
if entry == "stop":
        break
all += entry + " " #  add to list
print(all)
```

Comment: If there are two consecutive words, then entry will match the last word they entered. You're going to have to remember what the last word was. Perhaps you could use a variable for that?

Answer (score 0):

To stop the loop with two consecutive words, you can use `split` to get the last word entered and compare it to the current word.

Try this code:

```
all = ""   # store variable
while True:
    entry = input("Enter a word: ")
    if entry == "stop":
        break
    if len(all) and all.split()[-1] == entry:  # if same as last word
        break  
    all += entry + " " #  add to list
print(all)
```